# jquery autocomplete in MVC4 - referenced but does not work or appear in intellisense

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the jQueryui bundle loaded in my layout view and doing a view source shows it is referenced but "autocomplete" does not appear in intellisense  (only aria-autocomplete?)

When I try to run it I get this error in Chrome dev tools:

```
7
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    } has no method 'curCSS' jquery-ui-1.8.20.js:142
```

Code:

```
<input type="text" id="titleSearch"  placeholder="Job title e.g ASP.net Developer"/>


            $("#titleSearch").autocomplete({ source: [
                              "C#",
                              "ASP.NET",
                              "Java"
        ] });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was running the latest jQuery (1.8.3) so I also needed up update my jQuery ui (1.9.2)

Comment: And after you updated, did `autocomplete` show up in intellisense after that?